# How to Save Data into Tearadata Volatile Table from Teradata stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, teradata

I am trying to save the dataset that I get from executing a stored procedure. I tried the following query to call this stored procedure, but it did not work. Here is the error I get.

> CREATE TABLE Failed. 3707: Syntax error, expected something like a
>   name or a Unicode delimited identifier or an 'UDFCALLNAME' keyword or
>   a 'SELECT' keyword or '(' between '(' and the 'CALL' keyword.

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE #TEST AS 
(SELECT * FROM 
(CALL HP.SP_A_SEG_DIS (201605)) )ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Define *did not work* - did you get an error? If so, ***what*** error? Did you get a table created, but no rows in it? No table created at all ? Please be **more specific!**

Comment: You can't call a procedure from a `SELECT` statement. The result set returned by your stored procedure (I assume by leaving a cursor open and declaring `DYNAMIC RESULT SETS N`) can't be used by a query downstream. You can make the volatile table from within your SP for testing, or you can analyze the returned result set in your client.

Comment: Hi Marc, the error is CREATE TABLE Failed. 3707: Syntax error, expected something like a name or a Unicode delimited identifier or an 'UDFCALLNAME' keyword or a 'SELECT' keyword or '(' between '(' and the 'CALL' keyword.

Comment: Thank you JNevill. That is interesting and good to know.

Comment: Please **update** your original question with the error message! Don't leave it hidden here in comments.....